# How to create an external IP with these values?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I got to create an external IP for accessing this dash from outside. When I try kubectl expose... it still stay like this

```
root@mar:~# kubectl get svc

NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE       SELECTOR
alertmanager   ClusterIP   10.6.43.10    <none>        9093/TCP         36m       app=alertmanager
faas-netesd    ClusterIP   10.7.8.1      <none>        8081/TCP         36m       app=gateway
gateway        NodePort    10.7.2.10     <none>        8080:31112/TCP   31m       app=gateway
nats           ClusterIP   10.8.4.6      <none>        4222/TCP         36m       app=nats
prometheus     NodePort    10.102.4.2    <none>        9090:31119/TCP   36m       app=prometheus
```

Comment: What is the full command you run to expose the pods?

Comment: I used kubectl apply -f yaml files

Comment: Did you setup and ingress controller?

Comment: No. I used nodeport

Comment: You are making really hard to help you...we need details. The title is useless, the description doesn't make any sense, and your answers to our questions are too vague.

Comment: So sorry for the thin informations. I just tried to expose my FaaS server on a k8s cluster with two nodes. I don't know where the deployment files at. It's a good project I saw on github and I applied it directly and he created the pods and svcs but I am striving to expose something. I simply get the same response from k8s, you have to use selector, pods and objects of this style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not configured your FaaS-netesd service with "NodePort".If you want to access dash of FaaS-netesd service run this command "kubectl get svc -n ".It will list down all the services in that namespace.Now copy the service name and run "kubectl edit svc  -n ".

Just edit value of "spec.type" to "NodePort".After this you can see a **high port number** on hitting command kubectl get svc -n {name of your namespace}.

Finally go to a browser and hit http://{node-IP-address}:{high-port-number} your dash should be visible.